# extract the identical beginning parts of multiple strings

Tags: r, string, string-comparison, uniqueidentifier, doi

I have multiple strings (so-called DOIs) like this:

```
doi1 <- "10.1057/bp.2009.9"
doi2 <- "10.1057/bp.2015.4"
doi3 <- "10.1057/bp.2008.12"
```

How do I best extract the common beginnings of the strings?

The correct output should be `10.1057/bp.20`.

(My first guess was to use `identical()`, but that function can only compare *two whole* strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package ‘[Biobase](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html)’ has this implemented as [`lcPrefix`](https://rdrr.io/github/Bioconductor/Biobase/man/lcSuffix.html).

But implementing this oneself isn’t hard; here’s another quick and dirty version (careful, this was only tested on a handful of cases):

```
find_longest_prefix = function (strings) {
    stopifnot(is.character(strings) && length(strings) > 0L)

    for (len in seq_len(nchar(strings[1L]))) {
        prefixes = substr(strings, 1L, len)
        if (! Reduce(\(prev, p) prev && p == prefixes[1L], prefixes[-1L], TRUE)) {
            len = len - 1L
            break
        }
    }
    substr(strings[1L], 1L, len)
}
```